# Query returning wrong value when doing an INNER JOIN?

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I have three tables I want to join to calculate the balance = (purchase - payments) for a certain (party_id):

- Party (party_id, type, name)
- Purchase (purchase_id, supplier_id, quantity, rate, total)
- Payments (payment_id, party_id, amount)

The total purchase from that id = 20,000 and its total payments = 15,000 so its balance should be = 5,000.  After using this code:

```
SELECT 
    ((sum(purchase.total)) - (sum(payments.amount))) AS Party_Balance 
FROM 
    Purchase 
INNER JOIN 
    Party 
    ON purchase.supplier_id = party.party_id 
INNER JOIN 
    Payments 
    ON party.party_id = payments.party_id 
WHERE 
    payments.party_id = enter_party_id;
```

The output is incorrect:  1,000,245 instead of 5,000.

This is how I set up the relationship, is there a relation that should be fixed? [image: tables' relationship]

Comment: Which ID? There is no id in the `WHERE` clause or elsewhere. So you have included every purchase. Try selecting all your columns (for testing) and it should be clearer.

Comment: The problem is what is the cardinality relating those entities. Say for example you have many payments for purchase, then the total for purchase would appear multiple times and sum function is going to return wrong figure. I suggest you `select *` in order to understand what `sum` is actually processing.

Comment: Payments and Purchases are each the many side of relationship with Parties. This is why the dataset is so huge. You should do two aggregate queries to sum Payments and Purchases GROUP BY party_id and supplier_id then join those to Parties.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I `select *` and it's outputting every record 23 times! That explains the large value in the output, but now how can I fix this? what is duplicating them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must do 2 separate groupings of the table `Party`:
The 1st with `Purchase` to get the `SUM` of `total` 
and the 2nd with `Payments` to get the `SUM` of `amount`. 
Then join the 2 subqueries and get `Party_Balance`:

```
SELECT pur.party_id,  pur.total - pay.sumamount AS Party_Balance FROM (
  SELECT Party.party_id, SUM(Purchase.total) AS total
  FROM Party INNER JOIN Purchase ON Party.party_id = Purchase.supplier_id
  GROUP BY Party.party_id
) AS pur
INNER JOIN (
SELECT Party.party_id, SUM(amount) AS sumamount
  FROM Party INNER JOIN Payments ON Party.party_id = Payments.party_id
  GROUP BY Party.party_id
) AS pay
on pay.party_id = pur.party_id
```